# Why are the native client (nacl) demos slow?

Tags: google-nativeclient

On the [native client example page](http://code.google.com/chrome/nativeclient/docs/examples.html) there are two examples that graphics. Pi Generator and Conway's Life

Both of them use all of my cpu (well, one core which is 50%). With Conway's Life the cpu is split between nacl64 and chrome.

Why is it so slow?
I am using chrome 12.0.7

Comment: What do you mean slow? What are you comparing with?

Comment: @Viktor: even something scripted and not hardware accelerated doesn't use up all my CPU for Conway's game of Life. So lets say anything or everything.

Comment: I think you have a very strange idea of slow. Ofcourse game of life should utilize as much of your cpu as possible, to make as many iterations\sec as possible.

Answer (score 5):

They are supposed to eat up all your cpu. They are benchmarks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's pretty hard to get to work such examples with such performance if they were written in JS. These examples are very CPU intensive, and they are made to showcase what you can do with it. Performance is really close to native. It is really amazing.

These examples are ports of famous open source projects. You can download original project and compare performance.